# How does changing armv6/armv7 architecture to armv6 affect my iPad app? Will there be performance/stability losses?

Tags: architecture, ipad, arm

I need to change the the architectures of "Any iPhone OS Device" from "Optimized (armv6 armv7)" to "Standard (armv6)" for a library. I'm not exactly sure what effect will this have on the performance and stability of my iPad app.
If I understand it right, the iPad has the armv7 architecture. I'm not so familiar with architectures, so I don't know what it means.

Comment: Why do you need to change it?

Comment: A highscore library I want to use, need this…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't negatively affect the stability, but might slightly harm the performance on armv7.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - What does "might slightly harm" mean? When? My app uses coreanimation, quartzcore and other not graphic intensive tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The stability will not be affected, however the code within your library will not take any advantages given by the compiler nor the processor.  This will not affect the libraries that you are using as they will be compiled for the specific hardware that your library is being run on.

If you are doing intensive math in your library, you might want to consider creating two versions of the library (one for each architecture) however it doesn't sound like you are.

Figuring out exactly how your library will be affected is going to have to be an exercise for you after you learn about the differences between the architectures and how the compiler optimizes your code for each one.

Long story short, as you have probably already realized, you will probably not see any differences based on how you mentioned you use the library, however it all depends on how you code.